# Best Lightweight HTML Parser for Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, parsing, delphi-2009, delphi-2010

I need to parse out the values from some data from select boxes.

Example:  <option value="1">Apple</option><option value="2">Chicken</option>

Usage: If option = apple then get value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

[DIHtmlParser](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/htmlparser/index)?  I'm not sure how "lightweight" it is, but Ralf's components always seemed to be well put together.  He's also normally active and response on Embarcadero's Forums.

If it's a one-off and not too complex, you could probably split on symbols manually.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the standard XML Parsers...that is if your document meets the XHTML standards.

Answer (score 0):

Had searched for a while useful html-parsers for Delphi.
Got lucky with [htmlp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlp/) and [HTMLParserEx](https://github.com/radprogrammer/HTMLParserEx).

Answer (score -3):

To parsing small html, use regular expressions.

Comment: For the love of god, never use regular expressions to parse HTML